# Access Export Subform to excel

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, export-to-excel

I'm trying to write some VBA to export filtered records from a subform. I've found a number of post related to this issue and I've cobbled the code below from those post.

When I run it I get a run-time error saying:

> the Object '__temp' already exist.

When I click debug it highlights the line

```
Set qrydef = db.CreateQueryDef(strTempQryDef, strSQL)
```

Thank you for you help.

```
Private Sub ExportSubform()

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim qrydef As dao.QueryDef

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim bolWithFilterOn As Boolean
    Dim strTempQryDef As String
    Dim strRecordSource As String

    strTempQryDef = "__temp"

    bolWithFilterOn = me.subsearch_frm.Form.FilterOn

    strRecordSource = me.subsearch_frm.Form.RecordSource

    If InStr(strRecordSource, "SELECT ") <> 0 Then
        strSQL = strRecordSource
    Else
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strRecordSource & "]"
    End If

    ' just in case our sql string ends with ";"
    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, ";", "")

    If bolWithFilterOn Then
        strSQL = strSQL & _
        IIf(InStr(strSQL, "WHERE ") <> 0, " And ", " Where ") & _
        me.subsearch_frm.Form.Filter
    End If

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'create temporary query
    Set qrydef = db.CreateQueryDef(strTempQryDef, strSQL)
    db.QueryDefs.Append qrydef
    Set qrydef = Nothing

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acExport, _
    SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    TableName:=strTempQryDef, _
    FileName:=Replace(CurrentProject.Path & "\", "\\", "\") & strTempQryDef & ".xlsx"

    ' Delete the temporary query
    db.QueryDefs.Delete strTempQryDef

    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: And does it already exist before `CreateQueryDef` is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao):

> If the object specified by name is already a member of the QueryDefs collection, a run-time error occurs.

As such, you should delete the temporary query before attempting to create it. To do this, you could use code along the lines of the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strTempQryDef
On Error GoTo 0
```

Also, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao):

> In a Microsoft Access workspace, **if you provide anything other than a zero-length string for the name** when you create a QueryDef, **the resulting QueryDef object is automatically appended** to the QueryDefs collection.

As such, you don't need this line:

```
db.QueryDefs.Append qrydef
```